# "Unable to create directory /mnt/.local/share/nano/: No such file or directory It is required for saving/loading search history or cursor positions."

Tags: shell, scripting, alias

I added an alias out of my home directory to mnt/c in my bashrc file and assigned HOME to mnt so I can more easily get to Users. I am trying to modify HOME and the alias again, but when I do "nano ~/.bashrc" I get the following message:

"Unable to create directory /mnt/.local/share/nano/: No such file or directory
It is required for saving/loading search history or cursor positions.

Press Enter to continue"

Any ideas?

Comment: what were the exact changes that you did to .bashrc?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after creating a new user.

This was solved by running `sudo chmod 777 -R .local` by a user with permission.

Comment: It should be said that setting permissions to 777 is not recommended due to potential security risks. Directories set to 775 and Files set to 664 are what I've found to be the recommended permissions.